# Answering questions from users with reputation of 1

Tags: discussion

9 times out of 10 there seems to be no acknowledgement from these users that they've read your answer and found it helpful (or unhelpful). Unless they've taken the time to update their profile and username, is it worth trying to interact with users that have a reputation of 1 and have asked just one question or is it a complete waste of time?

Please can you answer using your own experience with this type of user.

Please don't think I'm worried about my reputation score. That wasn't what this question was about. It was about how can I best spend my time when I'm on here. How can I avoid help falling on deaf ears *an' all that*

Comment: Everybody was a 1 rep user once.

Comment: True...........!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stack Overflow is different because we should not answer for the sake of the question author but rather for the sake of the whole programmers community.

If you know the answer post it. That's it. If it's good it will get upvotes and you will gain reputation points. If the question author found it useful he might mark it accepted as well, but he's not obliged to do so. Consider it as a nice bonus.

If you want to personally help people, well, there are plenty of programming *forums* out there. :)

Comment: I think you just answered my question in one sentence. "we should not answer for the sake of the question author but rather for the sake of the whole programmers community" - didn't think of it like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say for a moment that you look through the site and discover out of 100 questions from 1-rep no-user-name people, 100 of the answers have no upvotes or accepts, and out of 100 questions from 2+ rep and a user name that isn't user123456, 100 of the answers have some upvotes and some accepts. I don't think you would find that, but if you did, what have you learned?

**Nothing.**

Imagine 200 questions asked by 1-rep user123456 types. 100 are decent, and 100 are crap. (The actual ratios don't matter unless they get to the 1-199 range, because so many more questions are asked every day than you can look at.) The decent ones get answers, and the questions themselves may get upvotes. This serves to "convert" the user. They interact with the site, they get rep, they decide to set a display name. Maybe they accept an answer which gives them more rep. They're hooked! And these are the 100 questions you find later that are from users with rep and real user names - **but they didn't start out that way**.

The crap questions are ignored by everyone, including the people who asked them. Those people haven't really engaged with the site, it's true. If a question was asked a week or a month ago and nobody has upvoted it, or answered it, the asker hasn't updated it or replied to any comments, well yeah, it's probably a crap question. You could always, I don't know, *read the question* to find out if it was crap or not, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was.

Now consider a question posted 30 seconds ago by a 1-rep user1234546 with no votes and no answers. Is it crap because of who it came from? Of course not. It might be that first question that leads to a fully engaged user. Or it might be crap. **You can't tell** just by looking at who asked it. You're going to have to at least read it. There's a good chance it's crap, in which case you can ignore it unless you have the rep to do janitor work (edit, flag, downvote, vote to close, comment with suggestions for improvement, whatever.) But it might not be. You'll find out when you look at it.

Comment: So you're saying you need to judge a question on the question's merit as opposed to the question author's merit? I'd have to completely agree with that.

Comment: I am indeed, @henrywright.

Comment: Thanks for the edit by the way :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no evidence that new users don't acknowledge the answers. I beg to differ.

New users sometimes don't know how this site works. Accepting, commenting and so on. But they learn it in time and in my experience new users accept answers to their early question someday.

Comment: I think Shadow Wizard hit the nail on the head "you're answering for the sake of the whole community"

Comment: I like the surprise of, *months after answering*, having it marked as accepted.

Comment: @brasofilo that is always a nice surprise!